# Listbox with empty column head

Tags: excel, vba, forms, listbox

I have 5 listboxes on a form and all of these listboxes have an empty "header" (separated by a thin line) on the top. The properties look the same as of those on other forms that have no "header". The listboxes are predefined on the form, loaded  programatically from the app, not using Rowsource method. Columnheads property is set to False. 
How can I remove the empty header? What didn't I notice?

EDIT: attaching source though it looks the same as all others codes for loading other listboxes that look well.

```
Private Sub LoadNamesP(lbThis As Object, aNames() As String)

Dim k As Long             ' aux

If lbThis Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "No input, cannot load, exit"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not lbThis.Visible Then
    Debug.Print lbThis.Name & "is hidden, cannot load, exit"
    Exit Sub
End If

Debug.Print "Loading list " & lbThis.Name

lbThis.Clear

For k = LBound(aNames) To UBound(aNames)
    lbThis.AddItem aNames(k)
Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the code that add the items to the list? And maybe a screenshot of your listbox properties. Maybe even some code sets propety to `TRUE`?

Comment: And what about `UserForm Initialize`. Any code that sets the listbox properties to `TRUE` over there?

Comment: @JvdV Thanks, the bug was there.